# Azure ACI not running still serving up an Azure functions page

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I deployed a new ACI using the option 'mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld:latest (linux)' from the azure portal. Once that's deployed and running, visiting the FQDN for the container load up page below. Makes sense.

[image]

However, if I stop the ACI instance and wait a few minutes I get the following page for about the next 15 minutes. Except mine says functions 3.0. After those 15 minutes, I then get a DNS probe error message which makes sense. If my ACI is stopped why is there a function app responding to requests?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate, but this may still be valuable information for you.

### The 15 minutes gap

The 15 minutes gap sounds very much like DNS caching. When I deploy a container instance in West Europe region with hostname "my-important-container" and a public IP, I get a publicly available DNS record for it like this:
`my-important-container.westeurope.azurecontainer.io`

In this case, DNS record creation is done by the Azure platform for you. Microsoft engineers have probably set 15 minutes caching as a default value.

Creating a DNS record by hand, you can specify the number of seconds for which it will be cached in the global network of DNS servers, so that they don't have to resolve it using the authority server, every single time someone uses that name to access a web service. 15 minutes caching provides the ability to serve only 1 request instead of 1000, if there are 1000 requests to a website within a 15 minute time windows (from the same area, using the same non-authoritative server).

If you want to experiment with DNS caching, it is very easy using Azure. For exmaple, using `Azure DNS Zones`, or if you don't want to buy a domain, you can use `Azure Private DNS Zones` on private VNET and see how caching works.

### The "Function app is up and running" phenomenon

This implies that Azure is hosting Container Instances on a common serverless platform together with Azure Functions. That IP address at that time is allocated to a serverless instance, but of course you have removed/stopped your container at that time, so the underlying layer is responding with a default placeholder message. It's kind of a falsy response at that time, because you are not actually using Functions, and your serverless workload is not actually 'up and running' at that time.

Microsoft could prevent this issue by injecting information on the context, while creating a serverless instance. That way, the instance would be aware if currently it is serving a container instance or a function, and would be able to respond with a more informative placeholder message if configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, your explanation makes a lot of sense and is inline with what I was speculating as well.